# Compare multiple rows values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date                 Open     High      Low     macd      signal     histogram
2020-08-10 11:37:00  21.0300  21.2900  20.8700  0.244226  0.226461   0.017765
2020-08-10 11:38:00  21.1350  21.1400  20.9100  0.225912  0.226339  -0.000427
2020-08-10 11:39:00  21.0800  21.1800  20.9500  0.215375  0.223902  -0.008528
2020-08-10 11:40:00  21.1000  21.2600  20.9500  0.185119  0.215284  -0.030165
2020-08-10 11:41:00  20.9900  21.1900  20.9894  0.177089  0.206796  -0.029707
2020-08-10 11:42:00  21.1000  21.4000  21.1000  0.205930  0.206604  -0.000674
2020-08-10 11:43:00  21.3002  21.7900  21.1700  0.248566  0.215929   0.032637
```

Now I want to compare column 'histogram' rows 1 by 1 and combination of 2 to 15 rows whether it is greater 0 or less than zero with multiple rows combination.

This is what I have so far:

```
if df['histogram'][-6] > 0.000000 and df['histogram'][-5] > 0.000000 and df['histogram'][-4] < 0.000000 add df['histogram'][-3]< 0.000000 and df['histogram'][-2] < 0.000000 and df['histogram'][-1] < 0.000000:
    print("Data shows correct")
```

How can I reference and compare each row, 1 by 1, for previous 2 to 15 rows and then print?

Also, I am trying to set a precision  with this and can do that `df['histogram'].map('{:.6f}'.format)`. However, when I reference the data it goes more than 6 decimal places in the dataframe.

Comment: You want to apply a function to a *rolling window* and that function prints something if all rows in the window are < 0 except the last row?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question you can iterate over the range of rows `2:15` on `df['histogram']`:

```
hist = df['histogram']
for idx in range(2, 15):  # assuming not inclusive
    if hist[idx] > 0.00000:
        print("Data shows correct")
    elif hist[idx] < 0.0000:
        # so something else here when it is negative
        pass 
    else:
        # do something else when it's 0
        pass
```

For your second question, you could use the `decimal` module which allows you to control the number of decimal places. You can read through it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).